# insert javascript var to thymeleaf url

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

How to insert *JavaScript* variable to *thymeleaf* URL?

*example*:

```
var i = x;
var actionCheck = /*[[@{/page/page1?action=add&amp;param2=i}]]*/ '/memberrki/checkCardNum?action=add&amp;param2=i}';
```

`param2` must be filled from `var i` ?

This is what I expected:

```
/memberrki/checkCardNum?action=add&param2=x
```

Comment: Have you tried to concatenate the variable? `'/memberrki/checkCardNum?action=add&param2='+i+'}'`

Comment: you do something like '/memberrki/checkCardNum?action=add&param2='+i

Comment: Thymeleaf code is processed at the server. So you cannot access the javascript variables which are defined at the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Simple perform some string concatenation

```
var i = x;
var actionCheck = '/memberrki/checkCardNum?action=add&amp;param2=' + i;
```

Or using ES6 template literals:

```
var i = x;
var actionCheck = `/memberrki/checkCardNum?action=add&amp;param2=${i}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try separating it into two variables ?

```
var i = x;
var actionCheckBase = /*[[@{/page/page1?action=add&amp;param2=}]]*/ '/memberrki/checkCardNum?action=add&amp;param2=';
var actionCheck = actionCheckBase + i;
```